# Mobile Meteor App - calculating nearby locations and storing as sortable collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, geo

I'm putting together a mobile meteor application that I want to use to list local (say within a 20 mile radius) amenities. I have a collection of these amenities with corresponding latlng data - I'd like to be able to pass the app my current location (using Cordova) and generate a list (/collection?) that is sorted closest first.

I have two specific problems that I'd really appreciate some advice on!

Can I use mongo's `$near` for this or should I be using a node.js add-on (eg 'GeoLib' - https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib) to do the distance calculation?

How do I generate a temporary (locally stored) collection of these locations to display in my list? Presumably if I don't use `$near` I have to iterate through my locations, calculating the distance on all of them and then returning any where the distance is under a certain threshold, but this seems like an expensive way of doing it when my location list will grow and grow.

Sorry, this is the first time I've attempted something like this; I'd really appreciate any advice from a more seasoned developer!

**EDIT - MY CODE (WHY IS IT NOT WORKING?!)**

I'm storing locations like this in a collection:

`Beaches.insert({
    name: 'Venice Beach CA',
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [-118.473314,118.473314]
      }
  });`

...

`Beaches._ensureIndex({'geometry.coordinates':'2d'}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) return console.dir(err);
  });`

I'm querying these entries like this (passing in the lat and lng):

`getNearBeaches = function(lng,lat) {
    return Beaches.find({'geometry.coordinates':
      {
       $near: {
         $geometry: {
           type: "Point",
           coordinates: [lng,lat]
           }
        },
        $maxDistance: 20000   //meters
     }
   })
};`

I can list my collection with a straight `find()` but my location search returns nothing, even if I set the $maxDistance to a huge number, or search directly on an already stored set of coords.

What have I done wrong??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fetch the current location, send it to server and subscribe to collection, filtered by mongodb `$near`:

```
Meteor.subscribe("amenities", {latlng: Session.get("latlng")});
```

And smth like this:

```
Meteor.publish("amenities", function (latlng) {
   return Amenities.find({
      location: {
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: latlng
          },
          $maxDistance: 20000   //meters
        }
      }
    });
});
```

You must have correct data type and indexes. And field `location` (-:

Comment: Thanks none! Just to be clear - what should the structure of my location field be? Currently I simply have lat and lng set as individual fields as part of each amenity entry but I can restructure!

Comment: Location must be an object like this type: `location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lng, lat]}`. Coordinates must be Array and order is important - first is lng, second - lat, it's MongoDB specific. And you have to add 2dsphere index to `location`.

Comment: Edited above with code - I can't figure out what I've done wrong as I've looked at quite a few resources and they all seem to concur with none's initial response (above)

Comment: First, did you add Indexes on MongoDB? And second, index must be `2dsphere`.

Comment: Look at the  [live demo](http://localgeo.meteor.com/) and my [source](https://github.com/n0ne/localgeo).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've got the location stuff working now (it turns out that my `$maxDistance` was outside the `$near` instead of inside. If I could upvote again I would!

Comment: OK here's one more question that I think I already know the answer to - can I return the distance between the latlng that I pass in and the coords that I'm evaluating? The results seem to come back in the correct order - can I access the distance that makes that sort work? (So that I can output the distance in my results - eg 4km away)

Comment: I think, this is question to MongoDB. Look at [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) link, specially to `distanceField`.

Comment: I figured as much! Frustrating that you can't access that distance from the $near results (seems like they know which order to show in) - thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You can [calculate](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) distance on client, make local collection, add fild distance and sort (-: